# Auto-closing a windows in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I have written a program to download data from an API. While data is being downloaded, I have designed a window to display 'Processing', however, I want this window to close after the processing completes.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: You should close window if process finished in event loop, or using method `write_event_value` of window to generate an event to close window.

Comment: Can you provide any sample code for implementing this, as I am not able to find any working example of this functionality, and I'm newbie to python.

Comment: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Multithreaded_Write_Event_Value.py